# Probe Request frames in 802.11n

Tags: ieee-802.11

I have two questions about Probe Request frames in 802.11n:

1. On which rate are Probe Request frames sent in 802.11n? Is it fixed in the standard, or can it be tuneable?
2. Are Probe Request frames sent in older modulation techniques to support older 802.11 versions? I guess this should be the same as the other Management Frames.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since probe requests are management frames, they are sent at the lowest rate in the network (1Mbps in 2.4GHz, 6Mbps in 5GHz). I'm not 100% if it's a norm standard, but this is at least an industry standard.

Comment: Thanks. Are they sent with 802.11n, or with older versions?

Comment: Management frames are sent using the 802.11b & 802.11a